# How to evaluate limits of these functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Good day,

I am currently trying to calculate the show the following.
Given the function $f(x)=(\alpha_1 x_1 ^{\rho} + \alpha_2 x_2 ^ {\rho})^{1/\rho}$, where $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1$. I am trying to compute:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{\rho \to 0} {f(x) = x_1 ^{\alpha_1} \ x_2 ^ {\alpha_2}} \\
\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} f(x)= \min(x_1,x_2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

To find the first limit, I was thinking of adopting a monotonic transformation of $f(x)$ s.t. $\tilde{f}(x) = \ln(f(x))$ and apply L'Hopital's rule. But clearly, it doesn't work as I've got two $x$'s.
To find the second limit, I am assuming that $\min(x_1,x_2) = x_1 $ for simplicity so the whole thing boils down to: $\lim_{\rho \to -\infty} (\alpha_1 x_1 ^{\rho} + \alpha_2 x_2 ^ {\rho})^{1/\rho} = x_1 $. I am unsure, however, how to get there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remark: This is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean. A proof of the first statement can be found for instance in the first box of the "special cases" section

Comment: Is $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 1$?

Comment: Yes, @Meowdog, they sum up to unity

Comment: This is an important property, it should not be left as an "accidental remark".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=(\alpha_1 x_1 ^{\rho} + \alpha_2 x_2 ^ {\rho})^{1/\rho}=x_1\left(\alpha_1+ \alpha_2 \left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right) ^ {\rho}\right)^{1/\rho}$$ and the factor of $x_1$ tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, using $\ln$ and applying l'Hopital works very well. Remember that you take the limit w.r.t. $p$ and not $x_1$ and $x_2$. I will furthermore assume that the latter two are positive, otherwise none of this makes sense. You can calculate for yourself that both denominator and numerator approach $0$, i.e. l'Hopital is applicable.
$$
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \ln(f(x)) = \lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(\alpha_1x_1^p + \alpha_2 x_2^p) }{p} = \lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \frac{\alpha_1 \ln(x_1)x_1^p + \alpha_2 \ln(x_2)x_2^p }{\alpha_1x_1^p + \alpha_2 x_2^p} = \alpha_1 \ln(x_1) + \alpha_2 \ln(x_2)
$$
By continuity of $\exp$:
$$
\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \exp\left(\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \ln(f(x)) \right) = x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2} 
$$

For the second one, please consider Maximilian Janisch's comment.